# Partial/Filter search from two text fields to select a list

Tags: asp.net, webforms, controller, crud

My code in controller

```
    public List<Addresses> Addresses_FindByPartialStreetAddress(string partialnumber, string partialstreet)
    {
        using (var context = new A09Context())
        {
            var results = context.Database.SqlQuery<Addresses>(
                        "Addresses_FindByPartialStreetAddress @number, @street",
                        new SqlParameter("number", partialnumber), new SqlParameter("street", partialstreet));
            return results.ToList();
        }
```

my code in webform page, I'm not sure how to implement partial search from two text fields to pull a selection of list.. I know I'm doing something wrong here

```
   protected void SearchAddress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchPartialNumber.Text))
    {
        errormsgs.Add("Enter a partial address number to search.");
        LoadMessageDisplay(errormsgs, "alert alert-info");
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchPartialStreet.Text))
    {
        errormsgs.Add("Enter a partial address street to search.");
        LoadMessageDisplay(errormsgs, "alert alert-info");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            AddressesController sysmgr = new AddressesController();
            List<Addresses> info =     
               sysmgr.Addresses_FindByPartialStreetAddress              
               (SearchPartialNumber.Text + SearchPartialStreet);

            AddressSelectionList.DataSource = info;
            AddressSelectionList.DataBind();
        }
```

I binded my list like this

```
          protected void BindAddressSelectionList()
    {

        try
        {

            AddressesController sysmgr = new AddressesController();
            List<Addresses> info = sysmgr.Addresses_List();
           // info.Sort((x, y) => x.Number.CompareTo(y.Number));
            AddressSelectionList.DataSource = info;
            AddressSelectionList.DataTextField = "street";
            AddressSelectionList.DataValueField = "number";
            AddressSelectionList.DataBind();
            AddressSelectionList.Items.Insert(0, "select ...");
        }`
```

[Click here to see what the form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTQrS.png)

Comment: Is it a typo, or do you miss .Text in SearchPartialSteet: sysmgr.Addresses_FindByPartialStreetAddress              
               (SearchPartialNumber.Text + SearchPartialStreet);

Comment: Yeah that's just a typo, even with SearchPartialStreet.Text  there's an error on 'Addresses_FindByPartialStreetAddress ' , although if I try to just call one parameter than it's fine, So I'm defiantly not implementing a multi parameter search code right